# Store one map with another index map Java

Tags: java

I want to store a whole Map in another Map with index.
My code is as below:

```
HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>> custMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> mapCust = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mapCust.put("fname", fname);
    mapCust.put("lname", lname);
    mapCust.put("phone1", phone1);
    mapCust.put("phone2", phone2);

    custMap.put(i, mapCust);
}
```

Here I have total two Maps `custMap` and `mapCust`.
So I want `custMap` as indexed Map with 10 sub maps of `mapCust`.

And here fname, lname, phone1 and phone2 are different for each Map `mapCust`.

But right now, I have all 10 sub Maps with same values like last value of `mapCust` in all 10 sub Maps.

Comment: because you are working on the same instance of `mapCust` all the time. you might want to reassign `mapCust` at the start of the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap` will hold references, so you will have to create new objects for assigning to each keys.

```
HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>> custMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Map<String, String> mapCust = new HashMap<String, String>(); // move this line inside the loop
    mapCust.put("fname", fname);
    mapCust.put("lname", lname);
    mapCust.put("phone1", phone1);
    mapCust.put("phone2", phone2);

    custMap.put(i, mapCust);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance of `HashMap` everytime you iterate

```
HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>> custMap = new HashMap<Integer,Map<String, String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
Map<String, String> mapCust = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
mapCust.put("fname", fname);
mapCust.put("lname", lname);
mapCust.put("phone1", phone1);
mapCust.put("phone2", phone2);
custMap.put(i, mapCust);
}
```

Earlier you were using the same instance of `mapCust` again and again.